# How to Update SQL SERVER from changes made in Textboxes and with a Binding Source

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable

Using:SQL Server 2014, VS2015, VB

1. I have a **Datagridview** that fills with a **DataTable** named **Table**.
2. I have several **Textboxes** that are bind with their corresponding values from the binding Source named **bsAllData**.

   This works perfect. It fills the **Datagridview** and when I click on a row it populates the corresponding **textboxes**.

   What I need is that when I make changes in the textboxes I would like to press a command button to update the SQL Server with the new values. This is where I am stuck.

The following Code is working to populate the Datagridview and Textboxes:

```
‘Button to display all records in the datagridview
 Private Sub btnViewAll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnViewAll.Click

‘Connection to the Server
 Using connection3 As New SqlConnection("SERVER=x.x.x.x;database=ITDatabase;trusted_connection=yes;")

‘Variables declarations            
 Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT AssetNo [ASSET NO], t2.TYPE
 From ASSETINFO t1 
 INNER Join TypeInfo t2 on t1.TYPEID = t2.TYPEID 
  Order By AssetNo ASC;", connection3)

 Dim Adpt As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
 Dim table As New DataTable

        Adpt.Fill(table)
        bsAllData.DataSource = table
        dataGridAssetEdit.DataSource = bsAllData

     txtAssetNo2.DataBindings.Clear()
        txtAssetNo2.DataBindings.Add("Text", Me.bsAllData, "ASSET NO")

        cboAssetType2.DataBindings.Clear()
        cboAssetType2.DataBindings.Add("Text", Me.bsAllData, "Type")
  End Sub
```

‘Button to Update

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click

 ‘After searching for days I tried the following but doesn’t do anything.
  bsAllData.EndEdit()
  Adpt.Update(table)

  End Sub
```

Thank you and regards,

Comment: `Dim Adpt As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)` creates an adapter local to that button click event.  You probably want one that persists

Comment: @lmalave, [Here is an example](https://contrivedexample.com/2015/03/14/a-basic-example-of-crud-with-datagridview-in-vb-net/)

Comment: Hi Plutonix, thank you for the suggestion, could you provide an example on how to setup a adapter that is persistent, would this be a Form variable?